# click through Meteor application with CasperJs

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, casperjs

I want to use CasperJs to click through my Meteor application and make screenshots

```
$> casperjs screenshots.js
```

screenshots.js:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    timeout: 100000,
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  true,
        loadPlugins: true
    }
});
//casper.viewport(1024, 768);
//casper.options.waitTimeout = 10000;

casper.start('http://scrummie.meteor.com', function () {
    this.waitForSelector('.project-item', function () {
        this.capture('home.png');
    });
});

casper.thenClick('[href="/Demo"]', function () {
    this.waitForSelector('.postit__description', function () {
        this.capture('scrumboard.png');
    });
});

casper.run();
```

Whatever I try I get eventually a timeout.
Is there something in this code that is just wrong or any other suggestions that can help?

If there is a better way to do this please let me know!!

Comment: Are you sure that `.item` and `.foo` are specific enough that they only show up when the data is actually present. Please show the target markup.

Comment: I've updated the post, the script now runs agains a public url